# Const модификатор в сигнатуре функции

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Добрый день,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void f_num(int x)
{
    cout << "int x" << endl;
}
void f_num(const int x)
{
    cout << "const int x" << endl;
}

void f_ptr(int* x)
{
    cout << "int* x" << endl;
}
void f_ptr(const int* x)
{
    cout << "const int* x" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    int* pointer = (int*)15;
    const int* pointer2 = (int*)15;

    int number = 0;
    const int number2 = 15;

    f_num(number);
    f_num(number2);

    f_ptr(pointer);
    f_ptr(pointer2);
}
```

Почему для указателей допустима перегрузка через модификатор параметра const, а для объекта по значению нет.

Comment: Проверьте код. `f_num` идентичен `f_ptr`, а должен отличаться. Конкретнее: у Вас там параметр `int x` или `const int &x`? Трудно ответить, не видя кода, который Вы *хотите* написать.

Comment: Хм. Вы не ошиблись насчёт сигнатуры `void f_ptr(const int* x)`? Может, вы имели в виду `void f_ptr(int* const x)`?

Comment: Как бы непонятно, каким образом ваш код иллюстрирует проблему.

Comment: Копипастил, чтобы создать Hello world пример проблемы. Обновил.

Comment: @rikimaru2013, хороший, кстати, вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном случае для компилятор просто воспринимает идентичными

```
void f_num(int x);
void f_num(const int x);
```

потому что на самом деле при таком вызове создается копия передаваемой переменной, и компилятору без разницы создавать её из `const` или не `const` переменной, он просто не сможет определить какую конкретно функцию вызывать. Вы можете передавать переменную по ссылке (не создавая копию), тогда сработает:

```
void f_num(int &x);
void f_num(const int &x);
```

Answer (score 5):

Потому, что в С++/С аргументы передаются в функцию по значению. Поэтому с точки зрения вызывающего кода объявления

```
void f(const int);
```

и

```
void f(int);
```

совершенно идентичны.

Это не так в случае указателя:

```
void f(int *ptr);
```

имеет право изменять данные, на которые указывает ptr, а

```
void f(const int *ptr); // аргумент - указатель на константу int, то же, что и f(int const *ptr);
```

Не имеет такого права (объект, на который указывает ptr - константный).

Если говорить о константном указателе:

```
void f(int * const ptr);
```

В этом случае функция не имеет права изменять сам указатель ptr, при этом вполне может изменить данные, на которые он указывает, но поскольку при вызове все равно создается его копия - то компилятор не отличит его от сигнатуры `void f(int * ptr);`

Вообще, модификатор `const` действует на "слово" непосредственно слева от него (кроме случая, когда он идет первым - в этом случае - на "слово" справа). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779540/c-const-pointer-declaration

---

Кстати, для внутренней реализации объявления `f(int i)` и `f(const i)` различны:

```
void f1(const int i) {
    i++;
}
```

Не скомпилируется, а

```
void f2(int i) {
    i++;
}
```

скомпилируется прекрасно.

Comment: Ну, не то, чтобы _совсем_ идентичны — во втором случае реализация функции не может менять аргумент. Но с точки зрения декларации, да.

Comment: @VladD, как раз дописываю ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Стандарт С++ 13.1/(3.4)

> Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of const and/or volatile are
>   equivalent. That is, the const and volatile type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when
>   determining which function is being declared, defined, or called.

...

> Only the const and volatile type-specifiers at the outermost level of
>   the parameter type specification are ignored in this fashion; const
>   and volatile type-specifiers buried within a parameter type
>   specification are significant and can be used to distinguish
>   overloaded function declarations. 123 In particular, for any type T,
>   “pointer to T”, “pointer to const T”, and “pointer to volatile T” are
>   considered distinct parameter types, as are “reference to T”,
>   “reference to const T”, and “reference to volatile T”.

Сухая выдержка по-русски:

> Параметры, которые отличаются только `const/volatile` спецификаторами,
>   считаются эквивалентными. При этом только спецификаторы на внешнем
>   уровне игнорируются. Спецификаторы скрытые внутри типа существенны, и
>   могут быть использованы для разрешения перегрузки.

Comment: но по факту то видим, что для указателей cosnt не опустился и был отловлен.

Comment: Хм, а какая мотивация?

Comment: @rikimaru2013, потому, что в данном случае модификатор `const` не является модификатором "внешнего уровня". Объявление `const int * p` читается "указатель на const целое", а не "const указатель на целое" (что пишется `int * const p`). Это вообще, ИМХО, такая интуитивно неочевидная часть синтаксиса С.

Comment: @VladD о мотивации другие отвечающие поведали :) Хотя порой выдержки из Стандарта нужно воспринимать как аксиомы. Например, в `D` [можно обеспечить](http://ideone.com/uzhRJz) перегрузку по `const`. `D` не знаю, просто пример привожу.

Comment: @alexolut: Угу, когда я писал комментарий, ваш ответ был единственным. :)

Answer (score 3):

Для указателей квалификатор верхнего уровня `const` точно также отбрасывается и не учитывается.

Например, данные два объявления в демонстрационной программе объявляют одну и ту же функцию

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int * );
void f( int * const );

void f( int *p ) { std::cout << "*p = " << *p << std::endl; }

typedef int *Ptr;

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int *p1 = &x;
    int * const p2 = &x; 
    const Ptr p3 = &x;

    f( p1 );
    f( p2 );
    f( p3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
*p = 10
*p = 10
*p = 10
```

Дело в том, что аргумент в функцию передается по значению. То есть создается копия аргумента. Поэтому не важно, имеет ли исходный объект квалификатор `const` или нет.  Его значение используется лишь для инициализации параметра функции, который является локальной переменной функции.

Инициализация параметра для каждого вызова функции выглядит следующим образом

```
int *p = p1;
int *p = p2;
int *p = p3;
```

Если в функции будет изменено значение параметра, то на исходный аргумент это никак не повлияет. То есть исходный объект, который передавался в качеств аргумента в функцию, останется без изменения независимо от того, имел ли он квалификатор `const` или нет.

Другое дело, когда указатель указывает на константные данные. Тогда нужно различать, можете ли вы менять эти данные, на которые указывает указатель, или не можете.

То есть обращаясь к данным через указатель, вы работаете не с копией данных, а с самими данными.

Кстати сказать, если вы передаете указатель по ссылке, то есть вы передаете в функцию не копию аргумента, а, фактически, сам аргумент, то уже имеет место перегрузка.

Ниже приведенная программа это демонстрирует

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int * & );
void f( int * const & );

void f( int * & ) { std::cout << "int * &" << std::endl; }
void f( int * const & ) { std::cout << "int * const &" << std::endl; }

typedef int *Ptr;

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int *p1 = &x;
    int * const p2 = &x; 
    const Ptr p3 = &x;

    f( p1 );
    f( p2 );
    f( p3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
int * &
int * const &
int * const &
```

Для простоты рассмотрите следующий пример.  Пусть имеются два объявления, одно из которых объявляет константный объект

```
int x = 10;
const int y = 20;
```

Тогда при использовании функции вида

```
void f( int x );
```

вы можете в качестве аргумента передавать любой объект, объявленный выше, так как функция будет иметь дело лишь с **копией** значений этих объектов.

Если же у вас объявлена функция как

```
void f( int & );
```

или

```
void f( int * );
```

то вы можете использовать в качестве аргумента для этих функций только первый объявленный объект, как, например,

```
f ( x );
f( &x );
```

Функция может изменить объект, на который ссылается ее параметр, и сам объект является не константным, его можно менять.

Но вы не можете в эту функцию передать второй объявленный объект, та как он константный. Его загрузчик программы может вообще разместить в памяти, которая предназначена только для чтения.

Поэтому второй объект можно использовать в функциях, у которых параметр ссылается на константные данные, как, например.

```
void f( const int & );
```

или

```
void f( const int * );
```

Тогда вы можете записать

```
f ( y );
f( &y );
```

Присутствие квалификатора `const` означает обязательство функции не менять тот объект, на который ссылается ее параметр.

Также обратите внимание на объявление

```
const int * const
```

Это объявление можно представить как

```
const int ( * const )
```

Вы можете, например, написать

```
int ( * const p ) = &x;
```

Квалификатор `const` в скобочках - это квалификатор верхнего уровня. Он означает, что сам указатель константный.

Квалификатор вне скобочек - это квалификатор того объекта, на который ссылается указатель.

Для ссылок вы не можете написать аналогичным образом:

```
const int & const
```

Ссылки сами по себе не являются константными (хотя для простоты часто говорят константная ссылка, что означает ссылку, ссылающуюся на константный объект). Это объекты, на которые они ссылаются рассматриваются как константные.