# Зачем нужны константные параметры функции?

Tags: c++, функции, const, константа

Зачем нужны **константные** параметры функции?

Нужен реальный пример использования.

То есть когда стоит писать, например, так

```
void foo(const int x);
```

а не так

```
void foo(int x);
```

**upd**

Не является дубликатом [Const модификатор в сигнатуре функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471042/397468). Там вопрос про то, почему нельзя перегрузить, у меня вопрос "зачем нужны". В ответах не увидел ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @Harry зачем вы закрыли вопрос? Какой из ответов отвечает на мой вопрос?

Comment: Не вижу особой разницы, но раз вы так настаиваете...

Comment: @Harry не видите разницы между "зачем нужны с примером использования" и "почему перегрузка не работает для двух функций с константным и неконстантный параметром"?

Comment: @Harry если там кто-то бы ответил на "зачем нужны", даже учитывая что вопросы разные, я бы принял ещё, а так нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно представить, что параметр функции - это по сути локальная (для функции) переменная. И тогда исходный вопрос просто превращается в "Зачем нужны константы?". Ответ на который, как мне кажется, должен быть очевиден:

**Когда нужно показать и гарантировать, что значение не будет изменяться после инициализации.**

В достаточно коротких функциях (в пределах пары десятков строк) обычно сразу видно как используется параметр, поэтому даже там, где он не предполагает изменения, обычно `const` не добавляют. Зачем засорять код лишней константностью, когда и так всё предельно ясно. Но вполне можно допустить и ситуацию, прописанную в код-стайле проекта, требующую писать этот `const` во всех возможных для этого случаях.

Есть и вовсе основоположники мнения, что по умолчанию всё должно быть константным (переменные, функции, параметры функций и т.д.), и только если возникает потребность что-либо изменить, оно должно быть помечено специальным признаком. Однако, в C++ такой способ не получил развития. А люди, которые хотели бы такого поведения, просто добавляют `const` везде, где только можно. Иногда здесь можно неожиданно получить фейл, например:

```
const T c = f();
g(std::move(c));
```

Из-за константности `c` вместо перемещения получим копирование.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/117557

Answer (score 2):

использовать константные аргументы когда они read only в данной функции это хороший стиль программирования, который дает знать, что данная функция не изменяет аргументов, и если попытаешься их менять при написании функции ide и компилятор будут подсказывать тебе об этом, например:

здесь аргумент value только на чтение и это сразу понятно по контексту, и всем программистам будет очевидно, что эта функция как берет аргумент так его и печатает не меняя его внутри

```
void print(const int value)
{
  std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

также дело обстоит с методами классов, в set_x мы хотим просто скопировать аргумент x, а в get_x модификатор const говорит программистам, что метод не изменяет состояние обьекта

```
class Dummy
{
private:
  int x;
public:
  void set_x(const int x) { this->x = x; }
  int get_x() const { return x; }
};
```

Comment: Ни разу не видел, чтобы в сетах писали константный параметр.

Comment: @bigsmoke зависит от случая, что если нечаенно как то изменить параметр, но мы то хотим его скопировать как он вошел первозданный в моем контексте

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы нельзя было изменить значение параметра внутри функции:

Можно изменить:

```
void yes(int i) {
    i++;
}
```

Нельзя (ошибка MinGW `cannot assign to variable 'i' with const-qualified type 'const int'`):

```
void no(const int i) {
    i++;
}
```

В качестве примера использования именно `const int` вы вряд ли найдете, а вот передача константной ссылки, или указателя имеет самое, что ни на есть, частое и широкое применение, и примеров сколько угодно

Comment: Мне нужен реальный пример использования, то что параметр константный и так ясно.

Comment: @bigsmoke зайдите например в какой то из хедеров стандартной библиотеки и посмотрите на сигнатуры функций, мы привели простые примеры

Comment: @Ildar вот такого типа пример мне и нужен, в какой хедер и какая функция?

Comment: @bigsmoke например в std::max из algorithm функция принимает константные ссылки, потому что просто хотим узнать какое значение больше без их модификации

Comment: попробуйте взглянуть [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/standard-library/cstdlib?view=vs-2019#getenv)

Comment: @Ildar разве? по-моему обычные ссылки

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов куда конкретно?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов вижу `int status`, а не `const int status`

Comment: Собственно, ссылка должна была открыться на функции getenv, имеющей константный параметр. Дальше на странице есть еще примеры

Comment: @bigsmoke https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max просто ссылки?

Comment: Мне кажется вы все путаете константные ссылки с ссылками на константу.

Comment: @bigsmoke, Вы спрашивали про константный параметр функции. Вам их и показывают

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов нет, вы показываете НЕконстантный параметры, которые являются НЕконстантными ссылками на константные объекты